# Documents bulk inserted with Couchbase Web not showing up in REST API response Java

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-couchbase

I have a Couchbase cluster running with a bucket and scope created, when importing json objects as json list on webconsole, I can retrieve documents via Couchase web console. But the same documents are not visible when I try to fetch them via REST API in springboot app.

Ironically, the REST POST works, and the json object stored via REST gets fetched via the fetch API.

Could you share what I may be doing wrong here?

Also noticed that the json object saved via Post endpoint saves _model as my model class name. and saved the UUID (my identifier thats autogenerated) in the metadata. Whereas the imported documents lacked the _model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whereas the imported documents lacked the _model.

This is probably the issue. spring-data-couchbase adds a type property. By default, the property is named _class and the value is the java classname (it sounds like you have overridden the default with _model). Queries from spring-data-couchbase add the predicate WHERE <type_property>=<class_name> . Data not inserted by spring-data-couchbase will not have that property and therefore not be selected by the query.  So the property will need to be added to documents in couchbase.